# how to use Datatriggers in order to apply different style property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Until now i used `<Style.Triggers>` and `DataTrigger` in order to apply different style properties to items (TextBox in this case) according to conditions.

But now i want based on a condition of `DataTrigger` to set the `Style` Property to a StaticResource i have defined elsewhere.

If i use TextBox.Triggers i get an error that i can not use DataTriggers inside it just EventTriggers which is not what i want.

How should i deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem to have found a proper solution thgrough style inheritance at least for my case. 
if i define Style like this

In the following code `ReadOnlyTextBox` is the style i wand by defult to have and based on Datatrigger on one property of mine `InEditMode` i rewrite - undo some of it's default style properties like `<Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />` that was set in the default `ReadOnlyTextBox` style

```
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InEditMode}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnlyCaretVisible" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```